# Mysql not selecting null values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null, return

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE orderdate >= "2015-12-01" 
    AND orderdate <= "2015-12-31" 
    AND values > 0 
    AND orders <> 'Returned'
```

The problem is that the query doesn't return the rows where the orders column is NULL and I can't figure out why.

Comment: NULL is considered unknown value so it is not equal or unequal with anything.You want  `...AND (orders <> 'Returned' OR orders IS NULL)` Also VALUES is a reserved word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sql language. Mysql doesn't consider NULL as value. So if you want to include NULL we must specify that.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE orderdate >= "2015-12-01" 
    AND orderdate <= "2015-12-31" 
    AND values > 0 
    AND (orders <> 'Returned' or orders is null)
```